# How to fix the phpmyadmin error "json extension is missing"?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xdebug

Today i have installed the xdebug packets. After installing them my phpmyadmin and different other softwares aren't working anymore. PhpMyAdmin gives this output: json extension is missing. First there was an other error displayed: mbstring extension is missing. I could fix this error by installing the zend-php-extensions. Im using Ubuntu 12.04 and the zend server for php5.2.

How can i install this extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json is installed with PHP5.2

go to `/etc/php5/mods-available/json.ini` and uncomment `priority=20` (remove the semicolon)

restart apache2 using below command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 13):

I had this error today. After doing some search it turned out it was caused by my upgrade from `Ubuntu 13.04` to `Ubuntu 13.10`.

The fix was simple: run `sudo apt-get install php5-json`.

Then I restarted apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Yep that fixed it here.

Comment: Yeah - this is the one for me too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the following file:

   **/etc/php5/apach2/php.ini**
2. Write the following line in the end of the file.

   `extension=json.so`
3. restart the apache2

   `$ sudo service apache2 restart`
4. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it worked after loading the installed modules json and mcrypt.

```
$ sudo php5enmod json && sudo php5enmod mcrypt
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Go to `http://yourserver/phpmyadmin` and take a look to check if it works.